# Add levels to a nested lists using time intervals in R

Tags: r, datetime, intervals, nested-lists

I am working with a time series in R. Here is the dput for for my data frame data_long:

```
dput(head(data_long[, c(1:4)]))

df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1631292095, 1631292096, 1631292097, 
                                        1631292098, 1631292099, 1631292100), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
                                        ), tzone = "UTC"), PAR = c(12.8977721, 13.304787, 12.9570063, 
                                                                   13.329419, 13.2725308, 13.0666774), chamber_id = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), 
                     oxygen = c(91.7022326, 91.6907562, 91.6682765, 91.6921759, 
                                91.6947788, 91.6675666)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have created a nested list according to ID (1 through 6) as such:

```
nested_data <- split(data_long, data_long$chamber_id) 

head(nested_data)
$`1`
                     date        PAR chamber_id   oxygen
15681 2021-09-10 16:41:35  12.897772          1 91.40699
15682 2021-09-10 16:41:36  13.304787          1 91.42332
...
$`6`
                     date        PAR chamber_id   oxygen
12545 2021-09-10 16:41:35  12.897772          6 91.49998
12546 2021-09-10 16:41:36  13.304787          6 91.50280
12547 2021-09-10 16:41:37  12.957006          6 91.50250
```

Each list numbered by ID 1 through 6 contains the same date/time column. I would like to further split these lists into time intervals. I created my time intervals:

```
flushing_times <- seq(
  from=as.POSIXct("2021-09-10 16:41:00", tz="UTC"), #Change the first flushing time
  to=as.POSIXct("2021-09-11 16:43:00", tz="UTC"),  #Change the last flushing time
  by="hour" #Change the flushing interval
)  %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rename(start_flushing = 1) %>% 
  mutate(end_flushing = start_flushing + minutes(2)) %>% #Change the time required to flush
  mutate(end_flushing = lag(end_flushing)) %>% 
  drop_na() 

head(flushing_times)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  start_flushing      end_flushing       
  <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 2021-09-10 17:41:00 2021-09-10 16:43:00
2 2021-09-10 18:41:00 2021-09-10 17:43:00
3 2021-09-10 19:41:00 2021-09-10 18:43:00
4 2021-09-10 20:41:00 2021-09-10 19:43:00
5 2021-09-10 21:41:00 2021-09-10 20:43:00
6 2021-09-10 22:41:00 2021-09-10 21:43:00
```

and tried to use hop_index {slider} function to further split my 2-level nested list into 3 level nested list (first level being data frame, second level being chamber ID and third level being time intervals)

```
hop_index(.x = nested_data, .i = nested_data, .f = ~.x, 
                         .starts = flushing_times$end_flushing, 
                         .stops = flushing_times$start_flushing)
```

However, I am getting this error message:

```
Error: Can't convert `.starts` <datetime<UTC>> to match type of `.i` <list>.
```

It seems like hop_index can only be used on data frames, and not lists. Would there be any other way I could create my nested lists?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of few rows of `data_long` and your expected.  Also, please specify the packages used (`hop_index`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited my question to add the dput. Hop_index is from the {slider} package

Comment: Your `flushing_times`, start, end seems to be having one problem i.e. start is greater than end i.e. According to `?hop_index` `Vectors of boundary values that make up the windows to bucket .i with. Both .starts and .stops will be recycled to their common size, and that common size will be the size of the result. Both vectors should be the same type as .i. These boundaries are both inclusive, meaning that the slice of .x that will be used in each call to .f is where .i >= start & .i <= stop returns TRUE.`

Comment: I assume that it is an issue when you tried to create a reproducible example

Comment: This happened during data manipulation but I assigned the correct column to my hop_index function .starts = flushing_times$end_flushing, 
                         .stops = flushing_times$start_flushing

Comment: sorry, I was just going by the name and not by the code you showed in the post.

Comment: I tried with your data.  It is working though there are nothing in the ranges (probably due to the data you showed)

Answer (score 0):

We need to loop over the `list` and this can be done with `lapply` (from `base R`) or use `map` from `purrr`.  Here, the `.x`, and `.i` seems to be the 'date' column and `.starts` and `.stops` are the 'end_flushing' and 'start_flushing' corresponding columns from 'flushing_times'

```
library(slider)
nested_data <-  split(data_long, data_long$chamber_id, drop = TRUE)
lapply(nested_data, function(dat) hop_index(dat$date, dat$date, 
     flushing_times$end_flushing, flushing_times$start_flushing, ~ .x)
```

Comment: I am getting this error message:
```
Error: `.x` must be a vector, not NULL.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
 Error: `.x` must be a vector, not NULL.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: @EmieWoodburn With your data, I am not getting any error.  I would say use `split(data_long, data_long$chamber_id, drop = TRUE)`